# Specflow (cucumber) for Load Test (Jmeter)

Tags: jmeter, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Is there a way to create JMeter load test plan from .feature files? I have been looking around and I did not find any existing framework or a way to use existing specflow's feature files to create JMX files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is currently supported.

If you use Specflow/Cucumber for running [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) tests (or your tests use HTTP/HTTPS protocol(s) you can configure your WebDriver initialization to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as a [proxy for Selenium WebDriver instances](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) so when you run your Specflow/Cucumber test JMeter will capture the requests coming from browsers and convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

This way you will be able to build a JMeter test plan out of your existing functional test and replay it with [increased number of users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users). See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) for more details.

---

As an alternative you can consider [Ruby-JMeter](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter#ruby-jmeter---) DSL or [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool which allow creating JMeter tests declaratively.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T,
Thanks for your answer.  You're right.  I did not find any existing framework to translate Specflow/Cucumber into Jmeter Test Plans.